# Using RegisterHotKey API with a NativeWindow class ?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use RegisterHotkey without adding a Form class.

Right now I have an "Empty Project(.NET Framework) Visual Basic" with two classes in it, as follows.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class AppCore
Inherits ApplicationContext

Public myHotkeys As New clsHotkey

Shared Sub main()
    Console.WriteLine("starting " & Now)
    Dim myAppCore As AppCore
    myAppCore = New AppCore
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(myAppCore)
End Sub

Public Const MOD_CONTROL As Integer = &H11
Public Const MOD_SHIFT As Integer = &H10
Public Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
Public Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32.dll" Alias "RegisterHotKey" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32.dll" Alias "UnregisterHotKey" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer

Sub New()
    RegisterHotKey(myHotkeys.Handle, 100, 0, Keys.F6)
    RegisterHotKey(myHotkeys.Handle, 200, MOD_ALT, Keys.F7)
End Sub

End Class

Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class clsHotkey
Inherits NativeWindow

Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    Beep()

    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Select Case CType(m.WParam, Integer)
            Case 100
                Console.WriteLine("ID 100")
            Case 200
                Console.WriteLine("ID 200")
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Now this will compile without errors and run.

In the WndProc of clsHotKey, I put a Beep(), but this never gets called.

The original example I used to build this used the DefWndProc on a Form Class, however the NativeWindow's DefWndProc is not overrideable according to the IDE.

I have tried rebooting the computer, in case the hooks for the hotkeys were just not releasing, but that isn't it.

I am at a loss what is wrong here. Are there any ways to watch the windows event distribution system, maybe find out where the message ends and why it does not trigger WndProc ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RegisterHotKey(myHotkeys.Handle, 100, 0, Keys.F6)
```

It is debuggable, you can see that myHotkeys.Handle is zero.  Not so sure how that went wrong, using Beep() to debug the code is a hint.  Not necessary, you can simply use a breakpoint.

You might have gotten used to the Form.Handle property, when you use that one then it automatically also creates the window to ensure the Handle is valid.  But that is not what NativeWindow does, you have to ask.  Fix:

```
Sub New()
    myHotkeys.CreateHandle(New CreateParams())
    RegisterHotKey(myHotkeys.Handle, 100, 0, Keys.F6)
    ...
End Sub
```

Works fine now.

Comment: Fantastic , that works great ! Now I believe I have the simplest hotkey+systray menu app feasible.  I never thought to check whether the NativeWindow would initialize it's handle, I thought that was basically it's sole purpose, to have handles for functions such as these.  Thanks !!